# scaladoc Ant task writing for multiple source directories?

Tags: scala, ant, javadoc, scaladoc

I wish to compile scaladoc and javadoc in a project with both scala and java in it.  The project has more than one source directory (each of which may have scala or javadoc).  I tried:

```
  <scaladoc destdir="doc">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>

    <src>
      <fileset dir="src"/>
      <fileset dir="tweetstream4j/src"/>
    </src>

    <include name="src/**/*.scala"/>
  </scaladoc>
```

and several variants thereof.  For the above variant I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/blah/build.xml:119: /blah/src/com/foo/Blah.java is not a directory.
```

where "Blah.java" is a file in my source tree.

I've looked at the [scaladoc ant task doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/98) and the [scaladoc man page](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scaladoc.html).  I'm using scala2.7.7final (because that's what apt-get puts on my Ubuntu system).

Suggestions of how to get scaladoc and javadoc out of "src" and "tweetstream4j/src"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and came across this. Those `<src>` elements don't seem well documented but I was able to put together something that works from various examples I found on the web:

```
<scaladoc destdir="doc">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    <src path="src"/>
    <src path="tweetstream4j/src"/>
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <include name="**/*.scala"/>
</scaladoc>
```

That will look in both source directories for all Java and Scala code and build one set of documentation for it all.